How to determine if there is frictional force?
Imagine two vertical wooden boards clamping a small object. Assume that the left board is smooth, and the friction from the right board is enough to prevent the object from falling due to gravity. Now, what happens when the left board becomes rough? Will the left board provide friction? If so, how much friction will it provide? Does the friction force from both boards depend on the coefficient of friction of each board?

By saying the left board is “smooth” you’re implying it’s frictionless. How can you be so sure the left board isn’t contributing to the total friction force?

When you way "coefficient of friction," that leads me to assume you are talking about Columb friction, where we model friction as a force that opposes motion which can be up to some constant (the coefficient of friction) times the normal force on the surface (the clamping force, in this case).  This is a simplified model of what friction actually does.  In many cases, it's a good approximation, which is why we use it.  But in this case, it is insufficient to answer your questions.  All Columb friction says is that $F_f \le \mu F_n$, where $F_f$ is the force of friction and $F_n$ is the normal force.  If you have two parallel surfaces offering friction, it doesn't say anything about how that force is distributed.  It just says that there will be enough combined force to keep the object stationary.
In practice, you will find that the surfaces divide up the forces required to keep the object up, but the exact distribution between the left and right board is not easy to compute.  All sorts of details, like the deformability of the object, start to play a meaningful role.  So what you find is that you need a much more complete model, with many more measured properties, before you can really figure out exactly how the division of the forces will actually play  out.
What would be clear is that you could hold that object up with less clamping force if both boards were rough, because you would have a higher maximum friction force given the same clamping force.  If the left board was made equally rough as the right board, it would be reasonable to assume that they could hold the object stationary using only half the clamping force in your original setup.  This is easier to determine than your original problem because we are intentionally driving both boards to $F_r=\mu F_n$ rather than just $F_f \le \mu F_n$.  Equalities tend to be easier to calculate around than inequalities.

One of my doubts is, if the friction from the right board is already enough to prevent the object from falling, will the left board provide friction after it becomes rough? After all, even if it doesn't provide friction, the object still won't fall.

@user1361001 The friction from the right board can be enough to prevent the object from falling. It's maximum force is enough. However, static friction is not obliged to provide maximum force at all times. For a simpler and related question, consider a chair with 4 legs.  Were you to sit on a chair with 3 legs, it is easy to calculate exactly how much force each leg gets. So if you have 4 legs, does one of them just not provide any force at all? Which one?  Intuitively we know that the chair will distribute the force across all legs, although it's not easy to calculate the exact distribution

Also, if you hold a heavy object in both hands, does one hand get no force simply because your other hand is capable of holding up the whole object on its own?  We call these sorts of systems "statically indeterminate."  They remain motionless (static), but there's not enough detail in the simplified model to calculate exactly how the forces distribute.

Ignoring creep, the left board does not provide friction if it suddenly becomes rough. (If you find the sudden emergence of mechanical friction far-fetched, replace it with an adhesive bond that sets.)
The clamped object has already deformed to slide downward somewhat against the smooth left side; it’s now at equilibrium, with gravity resulting in a stress state and strain energy stored in the material and various reaction forces (frictional and normal) applied by the rough right wall to maintain suspension. No additional upward reaction force has been needed so far at the left wall, and so none emerges even if it becomes available.
